# Does Faye work on the iPad

Tags: mobile, websocket, messaging, faye

I've been playing with [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) and have gotten a test rails application to work on my computer's browser (Chrome 30.0.1599.101), but when I tried to access the same page on my iPad the messaging seemed to be broken.  As far as I can tell, it seems that websockets, the technology used by Faye, isn't supported on most mobile browsers.  I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on the iPad and couldn't get Faye to work on any of those.

Is there a mobile browser that supports Faye or some other messaging library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Socket.IO works...

Comment: There are many versions of the WebSockets protocol. I don't know which ones are supported by your iPad (is it running Safari Mobile ?), but if it can help you'll find a compatibility table on mozilla developer network : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me Socket.IO will Works its aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and mobile device, blurring the differences between the different transport mechanisms. It's care-free realtime 100% in JavaScript.

For More information visit

http://socket.io/#how-to-use