# rails private-pub gem: chat does not work in iphone/ipad safari

Tags: iphone, heroku, mobile, faye, private-pub

I implemented the chat functionality in my RoR app based on the 'private pub' gem and Faye. I launched it on heroku and it works on laptop browsers, however, not on iphone/ipad Safari (messages don't auto refresh).

I found a similar question but was not clear about the answer/if there was a solution.
[Does Faye work on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946398/does-faye-work-on-the-ipad)

How can iOS Safari connect to the faye server/ pub channel? I have followed the settings as per the tutorial (http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/hello-or-building-a-chatting-app-with-rails/):

MyApp/config/private_pub.yml:

```
production:
  server: "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/faye"
...
```

Heroku-deploy-faye-app/config/private_pub.yml:

```
production:
  server: "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/faye"
...
```

Heroku-deploy-faye-app/private_pub.ru:

```
# Run with: rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "production")
run PrivatePub.faye_app
```

I'm hoping for a quick fix based on the config settings. Or do I need to switch to a different solution (e.g. socket.io, Twilio, Pusher...)?
Thanks a lot!